# How to dismiss previous modals when a new modal appears in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

**Overview:** In this code, there are 2 buttons. Clicking on the buttons will open the respective modals. Clicking on the button "input", will show the modal with content "input". Similarly, clicking on the button "output", will show the modal with content "output".

**Issue:** When I click on "input" button, the modal with content "input" appears. But when I click on "output" button, I notice that "output" modal will appear in front of the previous modal. In other words, the previous modal does not disappear.

My **requirement** is to ensure that when a new modal appears, the previous modal should disappear. These two buttons have to belong to two different controllers. My **question** is how to dismiss the previous modal when a new modal appears?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module('app',[ 'ui.bootstrap']);
            app.controller('testController1', 
                function($scope, $uibModal){
                    $scope.output = function() {
                        $uibModal.open({
                            animation: true,
                            windowClass: 'app-modal-window app-modal-window-mobile modal fade',
                            template: "<p>output</p>"
                        });
                    }
                }
            ); 
            app.controller('testController2',
                function($scope, $uibModal){
                    $scope.input = function() {
                        $uibModal.open({
                            animation: true,
                            windowClass: 'app-modal-window app-modal-window-mobile modal fade',
                            template: "<p>input</p>"
                        });
                    }
                }
            ); 
        </script> 
        <style type="text/css">
        .toolbarContainerPlaceholder {
            position: fixed;
            top: 30px;
            width: 10%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px !important;
            border-bottom: 3px solid #F7F7FA !important;
            background-color: #F7F7FA;
            z-index: 30000;
            min-height: 47px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <div class="toolbarContainerPlaceholder">
            <div ng-controller="testController1">
                <button ng-click="output()">output</button>
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="testController2">
                <button ng-click="input()">input</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't the modal close automatically when clicked outside of it? Normally when the backdrop is clicked the modal closes. Except if you changed that behaviour.

Comment: Yes, that is one work around, where the user will have to click outside and then click on the 2nd button. But, in this case, the user has the option to select the buttons without having to click outside. I am curious to know how to dismiss the previous modal when a new modal appears, in this case.

Comment: Ok that was unclear from the example as the template of the modal only contains "<p>input</p>".

Comment: I don't think it is very good UX to have that kind of behaviour. Opening a modal from a modal might be confusing to the users. Furthermore may I ask in which specific situation this scenario is needed?

Comment: This is the scenario in my project:   The page is divided into 2 sections: header and body. That header has three buttons "print", "share", "view". When I click on "print", the modal related to print operation will appear at the body of the page. Similar behaviour for "view" and "share".  These 3 buttons belong to different controllers. The code in my question tried to imitate this scenario. Unfortunately, I cannot share my code-base from the project.

Comment: Ok I don't know why the content must be displayed in a modal. But anyway,
when opening the modal. The buttons will be inside the modal too? Or the modal backdrop won't go over the header? In any case the modal should always cover the header too. I think the question you should ask yourself is. "Do I really need a modal dialog in this case?" A modal dialog is used when a user needs to give some input. Thus cancelling or confirming. Either way it will disappear when the user is done with it. If you just want to display data you probably don't need one.

Comment: Can't do much as that is the project requirement. When the modal is opened, the buttons will not be inside the modal. The buttons will stay at the header itself.

Comment: Anyway to do this, it would be best to have a overshadowing controller like "HeaderController". That just opens the modals. I don't understand why they need to be in separate controllers but I guess it is to separate logic. In that case I would start writing modalServices. Instead of opening them like you do know. That way the services will contain the logic and you could have the overshadowing controller opening the modals.

Comment: @David Maes Just to add to your comment whether we really need a modal dialog. In fact, in my project, the modals will be accepting inputs from the user. In this example, I was just trying a simple case of just displaying information in the modal. Hope it is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI Bootstrap defines a service called `$uibModalStack`. Inject it and call `$uibModalStack.dismissAll()` to close all modals. Then proceed to open your new modal with `$uibModal.open()`

Comment: This seems like a winner. Far simpler than mine and it should work as long as only those 2 modals are present.

Comment: @rupali317 I think you should try JC Ford solution with using $uibModalStack.dismissAll(). I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable for each of your modals. For example:

```
var inputModal;

inputModal= $uibModal.open({
  animation: true,
  windowClass: 'app-modal-window app-modal-window-mobile modal fade',
  template: "<p>input</p>"
});
```

Then when the other modal is opened, you can simply do:

```
$scope.output = function() {
    inputModal.close(); // This line right here is where you close the other
    $uibModal.open({
       animation: true,
       windowClass: 'app-modal-window app-modal-window-mobile modal fade',
       template: "<p>output</p>"
    });
}
```

Comment: This will only work if it's all contained within the same controller.

Comment: @MatthewCawley, good point. Didn't actually notice there were two separate controllers here. Which brings up another set of issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var uibModal =  $uibModal(definition)
 uibModal.close()
```

Will close the modal instance.

I think it would do so automatically (not 100% sure) IF you didn't have models created in separate controllers (is there a need for that I don't see here?)

Put it into the same controller and create uibModal1 and uibModal2 (might wanna have more clever names here) and simply when opening one call .close() on another if it doesn't happen automatically.

EDIT: Since you have to have controllers separated you need to establish communication between them. In this case, I would emit an event.

On button press of testController1

```
$emit("closeModal2", args);
```

in testController2 have a listener for the other emit:

```
$on("closeModal2", uibModal2.close());
```

Do vice versa for other modal, have a listener listening to closeModal1 in  testController1 and fire that event from testController2 when opening second modal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in my project (unfortunately i cannot share the codebase), the requirement is that the buttons will have to be in different controllers. The code in my question tried to imitate the scenario from my project

Comment: I have updated answer, unfortunately, I don't have AngularJS on this machine set up to quick test it and make an entire example out of it, but it should work.